# Apache rewrite for query string value not equal to a digit

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to determine the correct syntax for an Apache rewrite to send visitors to a different page if a query string value does not equal a certain format.

> URL 1: http://www.foo-bar.xqx/?video=123 (route one way) 
>   URL 2: http://www.foo-bar.xqx/?video=fgh (route differently)

The format for the value should be all digits *\d{0,x}* but nothing I've tried so far seems to be returning as I'm expecting. The most current version for the rewrites is as follows:

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}                 ^video=[^\d](\d{0,})$
RewriteRule     -                               /404.php$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `!` to negate a rule

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}  ^video=
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}  !^video=\d+$
RewriteRule     -                /404.php$1 [NC,L]
```

That will only rewrite requests that have `?video=`, but only if there's no number after the `=`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I'm not sure that I'm getting exactly what I want but it will definitely work.